# DataSpell jupyter notebook freezes

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I'm using DataSpell to code a GAN, and for some reason, after many iterations, the notebook just freezes (I print a "." for each minibatch executed, and at some point it stops)

There are no logs printed, and this happens at some random point (even with different notebooks/kernels), and nothing appears also on the jupyter serser logs

Any idea?

PS: I know that "it's vague", but I have no idea what is relevant for this question, so please tell me which infos you need and I'll post it immediately